# Where in scriptures is found the story of Lord Shiva punishing one crore Gods and Goddesses?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas

Lord Shiva was on his way to Kashi along with one crore gods and goddesses. He asked all of them to wake up before sunrise the following day, before taking a night's rest in Unakoti, Tripura. But in the morning, no one except Shiva woke up. This made him furious and he set out for Kashi on his own, cursing the others to become stone images.([I read from this](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.scoopwhoop.com/amp/shiva-is-the-coolest-god/))

In which Purana or scriptures it is written? Did those gods and goddesses never get life again?

Comment: As far as I know; the story of Unakoti is just folklore, it's not mentioned in any scriptures.